# ASP.NET MVC Index action gets called every postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, postback

I am new to MVC (and web development). Currently, using MVC 5 for my application.

I have a web application and UI is like in the below screenshot. Basically, it is a single page application and I need to load the grid at the bottom, based on the user choice from the radio buttons at the top. If Latest is clicked, latest user data is bound to grid. Similarly, if historic is chosen historic data is bound to the same grid.

My actions in HomeController.cs are something like below.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    List users = GetLatestUsers();
    viewModel.Users = users;
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Filter(ViewModel postData)
{
    List users = GetHistoricUsers();
    viewModel.Users = users;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Just to be more elaborate as asked in comment, I am binding to grid in my view something like this

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
/* Adding not mapped column, that renders body, using inline Razor html helper */
columns.Add()
        .Encoded(false)
        .Sanitized(false)
        .SetWidth(30)
        .RenderValueAs(d =>
            @<b>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Index")
            </b>);


     /* Adding "OrderID" column: */
    columns.Add(o => o.OrderID)
            .Titled("Number")
            .SetWidth(100);

   /* Adding "Vip customer" column: */
    columns.Add(o => o.Customer.IsVip)
            .Titled("Vip customer")
            .SetWidth(150)
            .RenderValueAs(o => CustomRenderingOfColumn(o));

}).SetRowCssClasses(item => item.Customer.IsVip ? "warning" : string.Empty).WithPaging(15).Sortable().Filterable().WithMultipleFilters()
```

Now the problem I am facing is, if user is viewing historic data because of a `Filter` action, I load the historic data in the grid. If user now navigates to next page by using pagination control in the grid, it is triggering a postback and hence going to Index action and loading the latest data always. Ideally, I should be staying in same page and show the next historic data to be shown in page 2.

Pleas help me on how to handle this scenario.

FYI: I am using [Grid.Mvc](http://gridmvc.azurewebsites.net/) for data grid, and Bottstrap for UI controls.

[image]

Comment: "bound to grid" needs expanding on for this question to make sense.

Comment: @spender I have added example on how I am binding it to view and to the grid. I have also added hyperlink to Grid.MVC demo in note at bottom of the question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `postback` in MVC. ASP.NET MVC is different from `webforms`. If you need to show a different set of data (page 2, page 3.. etc) upon click of pagination links then you need to write your custom code to do that. Otherwise you can consider `PagedList`.

To install PagedList.Mvc, run the following command in the `Package Manager Console`. You can use NuGet to get this package too.

```
PM> Install-Package PagedList.Mvc
```

In your controller, reference `PagedList`  and the Index method of your controller will be something like

```
using PagedList;

public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
      var viewModel = new ViewModel();
      List users = GetLatestUsers();
      viewModel.Users = users;

      int pageSize = 3;
      int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
      return View(viewModel.Users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

And your Index view (change the reference to `User` model with appropriate namespace)

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Users>
@using PagedList.Mvc; 
<link href="/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<table>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>

<br />

Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager( Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }) )
```

Comment: I have covered this part in my code, and would not solve my problem. BTW, Grid.Mvc control already handles the same strategy to do the pagination. Assume, I have loaded latest users via my Index action. Now user wants to see historic data and applies the filter - so it goes to Filter action and I clear the grid and load the historic data to the same grid. Now user clicks page 2 in the grid. This event will not be doing HTTP-POST to to Filter action, instead, it will go via Index (http Get) action. Hence, it will load the latest data again (ideally I should be showing page 2 of historic data).